# Sqoop import Issue(exclude operation)

Tags: sqoop

In sqoop i have 500 tables and i want to import 3 tables only, we use import-all-tables exclude operation, we have to mention 497 tables name, without mentioning 497 table name how we can import only 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use three single `import` commands